# good way to represent a excel sheet value in Java

Tags: java, excel, dto, apache-poi

Consider that I've a excel sheet in below format:

**person**
**age**



Foo
29



Bar
27

Now I want to read these values (using POI HSSF) and have to process them. What's the best way to do that?

Note that I do not have a Object Person in my application, becasue the values that may come in excel sheet is arbitrary (i.e. it may not be the person name and age). So, I need to use some kinda HashMap to store these values. In case multiple rows, is it good to have a List !?

Comment: Do you need to store any arbitrary sheet or is the example you give representative i.e. will you always expect two columns with headings in the first row and data in subsequent rows?

Comment: the number of columns may vary, in different excel sheets. First I need to read how many column names are there (in the example, is 2) and based on that I have to read the column values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Grid {
    private Row headerColumns;
    private List<Row> dataRows;

    public Grid() {
        dataRows = new LinkedList<Row>();
    }

    public Grid(int rowCount) {
        dataRows = new ArrayList<Row>(rowCount);
    }

    public void addHeaderRow(List<String> headers) {
        this.headerColumns = new Row(headers);
    }

    public void addDataRow(List<String> data) {
        this.dataRows.add( new Row(data) );
    }

    public List<Row> getAllData() {
        List<Row> data = new ArrayList<Row>(1+dataRows.size());
        data.add(this.headerColumns);
        data.addAll(dataRows);
        return data;
    }

    public Row getHeaderColumns() {
        return headerColumns;
    }

    public List<Row> getDataRows() {
        return dataRows;
    }
}

class Row {
    private List<String> data;

    public Row(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addColumn(String columnData) {
        data.add(columnData);
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is defined, make a class that accomodates all those fields.

If the format isn't defined, pass Row-s around, or Lists, or even DOM from excel-to-dom transformation. You have no choice. I'd recommend just stick to POI's native Row and Cell objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use map if you have multiple key values. And i didn't find some build-in class for this issue. You can try write some kind of wrapper.
If you don't care of speed use simple 2D array like this:

```
String[][] filter = new String[initial width][initial height];
```

it can be Object instead of String;