# How to store values from excel to some collection in java

Tags: java, collections, apache-poi

i have a excel file like the following,

```
**Method Name**            **Status Code**     **user**    **password**
getLoggedinUserDetails        400              anto          test
createRequisition             400              mayank       hexgen
excelMDM                      400              xxxxx        hexgen
createOrder                   400              yyyyy        hexgen
confirmOrder                  400              zzzzz        hexgen
```

i want to save the above details in some `collection` so that i can access `details by providing username and get the details like Method Name, Status code,and password.`

i tried some thing like this and able to store only `method name and status code`

```
package com.hexgen.tools;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class TestMethodsDetails {
    public Map<String, Integer> getKnownGoodMap(String filePath) {
        String key = "";
        int value = 0;
        //filePath="TestMethodDetails.xls";
        Map<String, Integer> knownGoodMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        value = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        key = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    }

                    if (key != null && value != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                        knownGoodMap.put(key, value);
                        key = null;
                        value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    }
                }
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return knownGoodMap;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMethodsDetails details = new TestMethodsDetails();
        System.out.println("Method Details : "+details.getKnownGoodMap("TestMethodDetails.xls"));
    }
}
```

the above code prints the following :

```
Method Details : {Method Name=0, getLoggedinUserDetails=400, createRequisition=400, excelMDM=400, createOrder=400, confirmOrder=400}

to be frank i really don't know what mechanism to use to store these details so that i enables easy access for me to process details, the user name and password will be different, i have given here some user and password for sample only
```

Kindly help me to do this.

Comment: I'm minded to say you want to find the online lecture notes for something like "Data Structures and Algorithms 101" and read through those - your question *seems* not to be POI specific but instead a basic computer science design query....

Comment: I'd prefer Andy Khan's JExcel to the Apache library.  I've used it lots of times with great success.  Read the Excel and choosing the right object/data structure to manipulate it are two different things.  You aren't clear about what your problem is.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857380/good-way-to-represent-a-excel-sheet-value-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use Object Oriented approach to create entities. Create a class representing your excel data row, lets say called Records and then put the objects of this class in a Hashmap against username as key. Here is sample class :

```
public class Record {

    private String methodName;
    private String statusCode;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    public String getMethodName() {
        return methodName;
    }

    public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Define a collection to store the records as

```
Map<String, Record> recordsMap = new <String, Record>HashMap();
```

Read the excel file, create a record for each row and save in this collection. It should be easy and quick to retrieve the records from the map.

Comment: Thanks for the post, very good point to start with +1

Comment: What about sorting, won't be cumbersome to sort the data ?