# How to share data from one arraylist to several other

Tags: java, arraylist

I have arraylist like that:
First arraylist:

> [ID 1 , Name aa , TestN 500, Type R , TestF 500.123 , TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2013 , ID 2 , Name bb , TestN 500 , Type R, TestF 500.123 , TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014 ... ]

method to add elements to arraylist

```
list.add(new Data((String) it.next(), record[j]));
```

How can I divide this list and add to another arraylist's (condiotion to diviade is Type and the count of list's is quantity of Type occurrences)

So if I have in arraylist 3 occurrences of TYP in exmaple:
Type R
Type T
Type Y

expected output:

> First arraylist:[ID 1 , Name aaa , TestN 500 , Type R, TestF 500.123 , TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2013]
>
> Second arraylist:[ID 2 , Name aab , TestN 500 , Type T, TestF 500.123 , TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014]
>
> Third arraylist:[ID 3 , Name abc , TestN 500 , Type Y, TestF 500.123 , TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2015]

Thanks for any tips and sory for my English

--edit

```
class Data {
 private String head; {getters & setters}
 private Object obj; {getters & setters}
    }
```

In this class I have data from .xls file

Head - is the string like "ID", "Name" "TestN" "Type" ..
obj - here I have array of objects like "1", "aa", "500", "R"

Comment: Can you make the question  more clear ?

Comment: Ok I try. How to split one arraylist to a another few arraylist where the condition to split is element on arraylist ?

Comment: There isn't any library method for splitting Arralylist based on condition. You need to code the method according to your requirement.

Comment: That's why I wrote. I expect that someone showed me(in example) how that method could look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you should change how you store the data. Your `Data` class looks like this:

```
class Data {
    private String head; {getters & setters}
    private Object obj; {getters & setters}
}
```

Currently, you create a new `Data` object for each field, so your list looks like:

```
[Data("ID", 1), Data("Name", "aaa"), Data("TestN", 500), Data("Type", "R"), Data("TestF", 500.123), Data("TestD", "Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2013"),
 Data("ID", 2), Data("Name", "aab"), Data("TestN", 500), Data("Type", "T"), Data("TestF", 500.123), Data("TestD", "Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014"),
 ...]
```

Note that the relationship between the fields is completely lost. How do you know that `ID 1` and `Type R` belong together? Relying on the positions of the objects in the list is not a good option. Besides, when you use `Object` as the type for all the values you lose the type information.

A better design would be to use proper types and store all the information associated with a specific record in the same object, like this:

```
class Data {
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final int testN;
    final String type;
    final float testF;
    // here you can use any other date type you like
    final LocalDateTime testD; 

    Data(int id, String name, int testN, String type, float testF, LocalDateTime testD) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.testN = testN;
        this.type = type;
        this.testF = testF;
        this.testD = testD;
    }
 }
```

I used the `final` modifier, so the fields cannot be changed later and have to be set in the constructor. You may remove it if you prefer to work with getters and setters.

Now each list element is a single record, and all the related information is stored together.

```
[Data(1, "aaa", 500, "R", 500.123, "Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2013"),
 Data(2, "aab", 500, "T", 500.123, "Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014"),
 ...]
```

We can create a method that will retrieve only those objects that match a certain type. If you are using Java 8 you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
static List<Data> filterByType(List<Data> list, String type) {
    return list.stream().filter(item -> type.equals(item.type))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
List<Data> typeRData = filterByType(list, "R");
```

And get only the elements which `type` is `"R"`.

Comment: @ Anderson Vieira There is one problem. Now I have class data class Data {

 private String header;{set get} 
 private Object object;{set get} }   header is String like ID,name etc. and object is date or number. It is possible to add type to that class or I must create new class ?

Comment: Edited @ Anderson Vieira

Comment: @AndersonVieira missing parenthesis `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: @Adamo It would be better to have a field for id, another for name, another for type, etc. instead of a `String` header containing all information. Anyway, I updated the answer according to what you have now. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AndersonVieira but my header was looked as  ""ID  , Name  , TestN  , Type , TestF . , TestD" and object values as 1 ... so my arraylist have header + obj value

Comment: @Adamo Couldn't you refactor your class to store different information into separated fields? It would be much easier to work with the data.

Comment: @AndersonVieira  I can but i have dynamic amount of that headers because I get it from file. I can't write in example (47 fields to headers) that's why I add that headers with objects to arraylist. Maybe my solution is bad ? I take that solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479882/how-to-store-values-from-excel-to-some-collection-in-java

Comment: @Adamo In the answer you linked, they use one field for each header and not a different object for each header. Even if there are many headers, it would be better to do it like that, so all related information is stored together. I updated my answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: Yes, that right. Thanks. I try to check it and answer to that post. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @AndersonVieira Working very well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that it is quite primitive solution, but if quantity and lenght of the arrays is known, it can by divided using simple loops:

```
public static void divideList(ArrayList<String> strList){
    ArrayList<ArrayList> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    int k = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            list.add(strList.get(k));
            k++;
        }
        listOfLists.add(list);
    }

    System.out.println("list1: "+listOfLists.get(0));
    System.out.println("list2: "+listOfLists.get(1));
    System.out.println("list3: "+listOfLists.get(2));
}
```

the output is like expected:

> list1: [ID 1, Name aa, TestN 500, Type R, TestF 500.123, TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2013]
>
> list2: [ID 2, Name aab, TestN 500, Type T, TestF 500.123, TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014]
>
> list3: [ID 3, Name abc, TestN 500, Type Y, TestF 500.123, TestD Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 CEST 2015]